# How to realize user-specific type-generic behaviour in Play?

Tags: java, playframework, data-modeling

Say I wanted to build an application as follows:
A user can log in and create some observing mechanisms, that e.g. lookup a twitter hashtag or check some stocks every hour.

1. You have to have a User object that e.g. saves email and password for the user to log in.
2. You have to have some Java Code that e.g. establishes a HttpURLConnection, for both stocks and twitter
3. You have to save user-specific settings for those services: e.g. userA wants #hashtag1 but user2 wants #anotherTag

For scientific purpose I don't want to have every possible combination of those observers (twitter, stocks, ...) but rather have an abstract class "Observer" that both "TwitterObserver" and "StocksObserver" extend or something.

The problem I'm facing is this:

I am not able to e.g. select all observers (no matter of type), iterate over them, check if modified and react on user-specific behaviour. To put it another way: I cannot have a generic "Observer"-Class in combination with classes holding user-specific settings for this observer.

Is there any design pattern or best-practice to model this behavior? I can't believe it's all that hard.

I'm thankful for every hint! Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

In your GenericObserver class create an application job to collect the specific types:

```
public class Observer {
  // common properties and methods

  public static List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();

  public static void respondUserBehavior() {
    for (Observer observer: observers) {
      // call each observer to respond to user behavior
    }
  }

  @OnApplicationStart
  public static class ObserverCollector extends Job<?> {
    @Override public void doJob() {
      observers.addAll(play.Play.classLoader.getAssignableClasses(Observer.class));
      // or you might want to loop through the list and filter out the abstract classes
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thats a way to iterate over e.g. TwitterObserver and StocksObserver, but how can I make those two classes behave differently for every user (be user-specific). Let a user have set a specific hashtag to observe in his settings - what I want now is to have the TwitterObserver check for every user that has some TwitterObserver created for himself to check and e.g. notify this user.

So how do I make the generic TwitterObserver access all the user-specific settings? I would like to store those user-specifics in a DB... I'm lost here